# WKInterfaceController's becomeCurrentPage not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacecontroller

I'm loading up 4 WKInterfaceControllers into a page based horizontal interface in watchKit. [image] When a delegate callback fires alerting the app that the screen has been water locked, I want the watch to segue to one of the Controllers (based on a user setting).  Using the code below, if the delegate fires upon water lock, the app will segue to `MainDisplayInterfaceController` as expected.  However, if the delegate fires in either of the other two interfaceControllers the screen appears to segue but then settles back on the original `WorkoutControlsInterfaceController` (i.e. 0) however the page control on bottom of the screen is on 2 of 4?  Could this be a WatchKit bug?

EDIT: one clue I noticed is that on the first water lock I get the above behavior. But if I unlock and then lock again, I get the expected behavior.

```
 class ConfigureWorkoutInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
       WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["WorkoutControlsInterfaceController", "MainDisplayInterfaceController", "SpeedInterfaceController", "CaloriesAndDistanceInterfaceController"],
                                                            contexts: [contextDictionary, contextDictionary, contextDictionary, contextDictionary],
                                                            orientation: .horizontal,
                                                            pageIndex: 1)
        }
    }

    extension MainDisplayInterfaceController: WaterLockStateDelegate {
        func didUpdateWaterLockState(_ manager: WorkoutManager, state: Bool) {
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.becomeCurrentPage()
                    }
        }


    }

    extension SpeedInterfaceController: WaterLockStateDelegate {
        func didUpdateWaterLockState(_ manager: WorkoutManager, state: Bool) {
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.becomeCurrentPage()
                    }

    }

    extension CaloriesAndDistanceInterfaceController: WaterLockStateDelegate {
        func didUpdateWaterLockState(_ manager: WorkoutManager, state: Bool) {
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.becomeCurrentPage()
                    }
    }
```